# Text not centering on custom UISegmentedControl

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol

So I created a custom UISegmentControl and it looks great, but the labels of the first and last buttons are not centering. I was told to put this in the implementation file to fix it, but it doesn't do anything:

```
[self setContentPositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(35 / 2, 0)
                        forSegmentType:UISegmentedControlSegmentLeft
                            barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[self setContentPositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(-35 / 2, 0)
                        forSegmentType:UISegmentedControlSegmentRight
                            barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

35px is the width of my divider images. I also tried:

```
    [self setContentPositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake([UIImage imageNamed:@"mySegCtrl-divider-none-selected.png"].size.width / 2, 0)
                        forSegmentType:UISegmentedControlSegmentLeft
                            barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [self setContentPositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(- [UIImage imageNamed:@"mySegCtrl-divider-none-selected.png"].size.width / 2, 0)
                        forSegmentType:UISegmentedControlSegmentRight
                            barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

As reference, here is a picture:

[image]

Comment: Looks to me like the problem isn't centering.  The problem is that the first and last segments are narrower than the middle ones.

Comment: Thats because for the first and last segments the dividers are not drawn at the left and right respectively so the text gets misaligned. The setContentPositionAdjustment is supposed to fix that, but it is doing nothing.

Comment: Sorry, it's not something I have experience of myself. But I'd expect the default to give you equally sized segments. And why would setting content position change/correct the size of segments?
How does it look before you add your own custom images?

Comment: There's a question here, with equally sized segments. Maybe it'll help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11808066/uisegmentedcontrol-wrong-customization-handling?rq=1